# about the slope of a function - intuitive affirmation

Tags: analysis

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ an open, bounded and convex set. Let $K \subset \Omega$ a compact set.

Consider $u : \overline{\Omega} \rightarrow R$ a continuous function in $\overline{\Omega}$ and smooth in $\Omega \setminus K$. Suppose that $ 0 \leq u\leq 1$ with $u =1 $ in $K$ , $0<u<1 $ in $\Omega \setminus K$ and suppose that  $u = 0$ on $\partial \Omega$. Suppose that exist $\alpha > 0$ with $|\nabla u (x)| > \alpha $ for all $x \in \Omega \setminus K$.

Now fix $x \in \partial \Omega$ and fix $ 0<k < 1$ .Then exist $y \in \Omega \setminus K$ with $u(y) = k $  and with $|u(y) - u(x)| \geq \alpha |x-y|$ ?

Intuitively this is true ... but I dont know how to prove. Someone can give me a help with a proof or a counter example? Any help will be apreciated.

Thanks in advance